# update column value using a range group

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Hi im new with sql queries i need help.

I have a table which have QuestionId from 0 to 8 but sometimes except zero a value can be repeated, what i want is top create a group from 0 to 8 and when other 0 occurs it will be a new group, instead of creating i want to give random number to SurveyID column.

```
QuestionID  SurveyID
    0         NULL
    1         NULL
    2         NULL
    3         NULL
    4         NULL
    4         NULL
    5         NULL
    6         NULL
    7         NULL
    7         NULL
    8         NULL
    8         NULL
    0         NULL
    1         NULL
    2         NULL
    3         NULL
    4         NULL
    4         NULL
    5         NULL
    6         NULL
    6         NULL
    7         NULL
    8         NULL
    0         NULL
    1         NULL
    2         NULL
```

i want to update the surveyID in group from first 0 before second 0.

I want to give Unique random value to the group form 0 to 8 then again a new random value to 0 - 8

```
QuestionID  SurveyID
    0         8888
    1         8888
    2         8888
    3         8888
    4         8888
    4         8888
    5         8888
    6         8888
    7         8888
    7         8888
    8         8888
    8         8888
    0         1232
    1         1232
    2         1232
    3         1232
```

I want this to be done.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: First and second 0 in rapport with what?do you have an identity column?

Comment: @MohsinMushtaq It's not very clear what you want. Can you add a sample output?

Comment: @Szymon i want to update SurveyID column, from first 0 occurrence to 8 with a random value, and when the next zero occurs the update random value will change and will be stored in SurveyID column.

Comment: Is there any column that would give an order?

Comment: @szymon i have edited my question i have only two columns and the surveyID column contains NULL what i want is to update surveyID using the group range

Comment: @MohsinMushtaq The problem is, there's no practical way to guarantee the order in which records will be returned in a select query in absence of anything that could give you an order. You should have at least an autoincrement primary key column.

Comment: @Szymon primary key is there, which is auto increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE query to generate `SurveyId` the way you want. I assumed that your primary key column is named `Id` and table `seq` - please replace that. You can also use a different way to generate random numbers - up to you.

```
with cte as
(
    select Id, questionId, convert(int, rand() * Id * 1000) as surverId 
    from seq 
    where questionId = 0

    union all

    select seq.Id, seq.questionId, cte.surverId
    from seq
    inner join cte on cte.Id + 1 = seq.Id
    where seq.questionId <> 0
)

merge seq as target
using (select * from cte) as source (Id, questionId, surveyId)
on (target.Id = source.Id)
when matched then
    update set target.SurveyId = source.surveyId;
```

Comment: just perfect but another help is there a way i can update and set the surveyID values, cause right now it is creating a new table and showing and is just perfect what i want but can i get to update the value to the surveyId

Comment: oops, sorry, forgot the update part. See my answer now.